# Get woocommerce coupon code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

With woocommerce i can set a coupon code for discount. Is it possible to get the coupon code that the user filled in. I want the shop owner to get a mail with the coupon code the user filled in. Is there a hook that can capture the coupon code field data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [woocommerce_applied_coupon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100557/check-if-coupon-is-applied-in-woo-commerce) hook. You find the "implementation" in the class [WC_Cart (
method apply_coupon)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1510-1599)

Usage example:

```
function my_little_coupon_func($coupon_code)
{
    echo "coupon is correct: ". $coupon_code;

    // now send your email

}

add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'my_little_coupon_func');
```